# Anti-Vibration mats for top loading washer?

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

I am getting a new washer/dryer set.  I originally had a front loader set, but it started smoking and I got tired of the front loaders.  They will be installed upstairs and I was curious if the anti-vibration mats actually work? Does it depend on location? I found some selling online, but do you actually need to get one of those or can you just use something else?

Also, I was thinking if the washer/dryer come with feet, isn't it best to just have the feet flush with the bottom of the washer/dryer so you avoid the feet being out of balance?

Comment: I have a <1yr old mid-range pair (which I think cost a tad over $2000), which were marketed as having some kind of anti-vibration feature (inner housing detached from the shell, or something like that). They are installed on the first floor, and there is practically no vibration, to the point that you can hear the washer from the adjacent rooms (but nowhere else) when it's in the fastest part of the spin cycle. 9 year old house; 2x8 joists; the wall the pair are against is sitting over a steel I-beam, and another wall in the laundry room is sitting on the foundation. No mats/feet/etc. YMMV.

Comment: re: "isn't it best to just have the feet flush with the bottom of the washer/dryer", no. The feet should be adjusted so that the washer/dryer is level. If your floor is perfectly level and the feet are perfectly manufactured then "flush" might the right position. However, that is extremely unlikely. Follow the manufacturer's installation instructions.

Comment: @long neck - Good point

Answer (score 1):

Yes they work.  They distribute weight across a wider area and also act as shocks.

However the most important thing is to make sure that your legs are firmly on the ground and the weight of the wash machine is evenly distributed across all 4 legs.  If you don't do this then the mats become useless.

Also since this is a DIY site I will point out what I use on my washer.

1. Buy cheap plastic party cups.
2. Buy silicone caulk.
3. Cut party cups so that they are only 1.5" tall.
4. Fill to at least a .5" (up to .75") - all cups should be filled equally.
5. Let silicone cure (could take a few days).
6. Balance wash machine.
7. Sit cups under.
8. Notice that cups make a scratchy sound so put felt pad under them (this could be step 6).

Comment: I have been searching around for vibration mats for top loaders, but they all seem to be made for front loaders. Do front loaders shake more than top loaders?

Comment: Yes front loader (I have one) shake a lot more since there is downward force.  However a top loader that is way off balance can actually shake harder.  Really if your top loader is well balanced you could probably just put some rubber tiles under it (kid's floor tiles or garage tiles)